# Difference between storing Integers and Strings in Redis

Tags: redis

Any difference between these two commands?

```
LPUSH myset 123
LPUSH myset "123"
```

I want to store about 5 million integers and I want to do it in the most efficient way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there is no difference; both are stored as strings. From [redis.io](http://redis.io/topics/data-types#lists):

> Redis Lists are simply lists of strings, sorted by insertion order.

Depending on your usage, you may want to consider using a [set](http://redis.io/topics/data-types#sets), rather than a list.

Comment: From the link that you have shared, it also says that set also stores integers internally as strings. So, Can it be said that integers can't be natively stored in redis ?